# Передать значение accept в компонент

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Необходимо, чтобы при клике на кнопку, окно загрузки файлов открывалось с определенным accept. В моем примере, accept применяется уже после того, как окно загрузки откроется. Библиотека Element-ui  https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return { 
      visible: false, 
      accept: '' 
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
  <el-upload class="upload-demo" :accept="accept" action="/">
    <el-button size="small"  @click.native="accept = '.txt'">Upload txt</el-button>
    <el-button size="small" @click.native="accept = '.png'">Upload png</el-button>
  </el-upload>
  
</div>
```

Comment: добавь ссылку на справку по библиотеке компонентов, которую ты используешь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** Вызов окна выбора файла происходит по клику на элементе `el-upload`. Можете убедиться в этом - между кнопками расстояние, и оно тоже кликабельное.

**2** Вы изменяете свойство напрямую: `accept = '.txt'`. Грубо говоря - изменение попадает в очередь обновления DOM, пока не будет завершено текущее событие. Т.е. в момент открытия окна выбора файлов, DOM еще не обновился.

> На всякий случай напомним, что во Vue обновление DOM выполняется асинхронно. Каждый раз, когда обнаруживается изменение в данных, создаётся очередь, которая используется в качестве буфера для этого и последующих изменений, происходящих в текущей итерации ("tick") цикла событий. ... В следующей итерации цикла событий Vue разбирает очередь и выполняет актуальные обновления. *--[источник](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)*

Это тот самый случай, когда можно было бы применить `this.$nextTick`. Но в примере ниже использовано вычисляемое свойство.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    accept: ''
  },

  computed: {
    changedAccept() {
      return this.accept
    }
  },

  methods: {
    changeAccept(type, event) {
      this.accept = type
    },

    applyAccept(event) {
      // Если не выбран тип файлов,
      // то отменяем вызов окна выбора файлов.
      if (!this.accept) {
        event.preventDefault()
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <el-upload class="upload-demo" :accept="changedAccept" action="/" @click.native="applyAccept">
    <el-button size="small" @click="changeAccept('audio/*', $event)">Upload audio</el-button>
    <el-button size="small" @click="changeAccept('image/png', $event)">Upload png</el-button>
  </el-upload>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вы, конечно, не поверите - да я и сам, в замешательстве - но локально, у меня, такой подход не работает. А идея у Вас хорошая

Comment: У меня тоже не работало, целый час потратил. Уже хардкодить стал ч/з `event.currentTarget.querySelector('input[type="file"]').accept = this.accept`. А потом бац и заработало. В чем проблема была так и не понял. Может в версии `vue`? В примере 2.6.10

Comment: проверил, Вы правы, дело в версии Vue, благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Это нельзя считать ответом, однако как комментарий он слишком  длинный.

Если проследить когда отрисовывается элемент, создается впечатление что каждый раз работает предварительно сгенеренная копия компонента. Т.е. первый рендер компонента происходит не по кнопке, а  при первом выполнении кода, а кнопка запускает следущую генерацию компонента,  но отрисовывает предыдущую. Если предполагается что это правильное поведение компонента, то предположу что для того чтобы можно было открыть одновременно несколько аплоадеров по одной кнопке. Если же одновременное открытие не предполагается, то возможно это бага ?

Будет крайне интересно если найдете ответ.